# how can I scan for a pattern across multiple clusters?

Tags: ruby, redis

I have several key patterns

redis ruby gem version 4.2.5

```
app:namespace1:{id}
app:namespace2:{id}
app:namespace1:{id}:nested1
app:namespace2:{id}:nested2
app:whatever1
app:whatever2
```

How can I scan for everything `app:*`?

so far if i can for `app:*` I only get top level non nested values, like

```
app:whatever1
app:whatever2
```

```rb
def match_keys(pattern)
  @redis ||= init_connection
  all_keys = []
  cursor = 0
  loop do
    cursor, keys = @redis.scan(cursor, match: pattern)
    all_keys += keys
    break if cursor == '0'
  end
  all_keys.uniq
end

match_keys 'app:*'
#=> ["app:whatever1", "app:whatever2"]
```

I need it to return the entire `app:*` namespace keys including all the children keys

---

#### Discovery

it looks like my issue is not related to the search string, its because my redis environment runs in a clustered environment, so the keys are spread across multiple clusters, and the cluster responds back with the keys on its own node but not from the others

so how can I get my redis ruby cluster to scan all matching keys across clusters?

here is my cluster config

```rb
def init_connection
  config = {
    cluster: [
      "redis://#{ENV['REDIS_HOST_1']}",
      "redis://#{ENV['REDIS_HOST_2']}",
      "redis://#{ENV['REDIS_HOST_3']}"
    ],
    replica: true
  }
  @redis ||= ::Redis.new(config)
end
```

according to this post [how to use redis scan in cluster enviroment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51498737/how-to-use-redis-scan-in-cluster-enviroment)

it seems like I need to figure out a way to loop over each node, but i cant find any documentation for doing that

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider upgrading `redis-rb`?

In the latest versions clustering support [was moved](https://github.com/redis/redis-rb/blob/master/lib/redis.rb#L136) into a `redis-clustering` gem, which in turns uses `redis-cluster-client` under the hood.

It seems that the latter [performs scan across all nodes](https://github.com/redis-rb/redis-cluster-client/blob/2a48105c19e7229f8da48336fb71700292416262/lib/redis_client/cluster/router.rb#L141), so high chances are that with the latest redis-rb you won't need to raise the sun manually.

Comment: main bummer is that i use ruby 2.4.1 in most of my older apps and this requires >= 2.7.0, but it might be something I will update for in order to use